# Basepath argument is not fully qualified. Parameter name: basePath. I can not use code completion

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just open a .py file on visual-studio-code. And I got a message:Basepath argument is not fully qualified.
Parameter name: basePath. And I can not use python completion. The source of this message is Python(Extension) of Microsoft.
[Here is image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM4Fh.png)

Comment: Where is this message coming from, and what did you do to get it?

Comment: I just open a .py file on visual-studio-code. The source of this message is Python(Extension)  of Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today, and I opened a folder in VSCode(The path of you .py file. You can see the option in your image). It seems that it works for me now. I'm not sure whether it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks！It works for me too. It seems that I did not specify Bathpath. After opening the folder, I could use it normally.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me, it started today.

I checked my Python install, python path in sys, reinstalled VSCode and no changes.

Im using Python 3.7, win 10.

In the end what solved it for me was in settings.json, in VSCode, set "python.jediEnabled": true and after that VSCode prompted me with a warning that one of the extensions uses the language server (sorry i forgot the name of the extension, it was an old python autocomplete extension), after removing that extension everything was working fine.

As far as i understand it was a problem with the ms language server, jediEnabled setting configures the VSCode to use Jedi as the IntelliSense engine instead of Microsoft Python Language Server, some extensions require ms lang server so if you remove them you should be good.

Give it a try, hope it helps.

Comment: It seems that it does not work for me. After setting it true, visual-studio-code just use jedi rather than language server.

Comment: Yeah, that's what jediEnabled true does, it sets jedi as default, if you depend on the lang server try the hard reset of VS like Supaslash suggested, it should work if the problem is in the VSCode itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday and solved it this afternoon.
The source of this message is also Python(Extension) of Microsoft.
But, and i assume this is maybe the same for you, it was linked to "IntelliCode extension for VS Code (preview)" which asked me to activate pylit.

So the only way i found to repair the software was to delete my preferences files **to reset Visual Studio Code** and boot like the first time.
Then i re-installed my extensions and preferences.

You do not need to uninstall the soft.
Note that uninstalling Visual Studio Code won't change anything if you don't delete manually the preferences files.

Here how to do it on Windows :
https://filljoyner.com/2018/08/18/how-to-reset-visual-studio-code-on-windows/

Comment: I guess there is a better, softer way. But from far as i know, if the solution given by Nikola C. doesn't work for you, this one, as restrictive as it is, should always work.